# How does this C code work but the other says L-value required?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, increment

This code works fine when b is incremented and a is printed upon increment

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a[] = {10,20,30,40,50}, *p, j;
int *b = a;
for(j=0;j<5;j++)
{
printf("%d\n",*b);
b++;
}
return 0;
}
```

What happens here? What effect does a++ have here to suggest `lvalue` is required. Does a++ move to a point after all the elements of the array a?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a[] = {10,20,30,40,50}, *p, j;
for(j=0;j<5;j++)
{
printf("%d\n",*a);
a++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The fact that arrays decay to a pointers does not mean that they behave as pointers....

Comment: Read this for the difference between a pointer and an array in C http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c

Comment: @LPs *The fact that arrays decay to a pointer ...* I prefer to think of the decay as "decays to *the address of the array*" instead of a pointer.  The "address of the array" can't change, and can't be changed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, it is reasonable, maybe clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is an array which decays into a (unmodifiable) pointer to the array (and only and always to the array) when used in pointer context. So it cannot be modified, so `a++` doesn't work.

`b` is a pointer which can point everywhere and thus as well can be modified, so `b++` works.

Comment: It wouldn't be a stretch to say `a` is a `final` pointer, would it?

Comment: @Shiva it would be a stretch. `a` is an array, and arrays can't be incremented.

Comment: I wonder if in 100 years time there will still be people who think arrays are pointers

Comment: @Fredrik it's not an address, and the name designates the entire array, not the first element.It decays in any expression other than `sizeof` `_Alignof`, `++` `--`.

Comment: @Fredrik yes, variables are labels for memory locations... but `a` is a label for the location of the entire array (NOT for the address of that location, for just for the first element)

Comment: `sizeof x` is the same semantic for all types. If you think it is special for arrays that just shows you don't understand arrays. And yes there is a location for the whole array. Objects have a location. (That's what the "l" in "lvalue" stands for)

Comment: @M.M *it's not an address ...*  It is "converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to
*type*
’’  that  points
to  the  initial  element  of  the  array  object  and  is  not  an  lvalue."  Which would be an address, no?  It's quacking - it's a duck.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The result of the conversion is an address. The array is not an address.